# How Do I Make an API Call from Python v2.7.13 When the Requests Module Isn't Available

Tags: python, python-requests

**Good-day Folks,**

I am writing a small Python script that will be used on a **Ubiquiti EdgeRouter 12P** to make an API Call, using Digest Authentication, against another router for some JSON data.  This is my first attempt at writing a Python script and I have been able to do this using the Requests module, but only in a Python v3.x.y environment.  As I was writing my script, I discovered that the Python version on the EdgeRouter is v2.7.13 and the Requests module isn't installed/loaded.

I have attempted to do a `pip install requests` but it fails with an `invalid syntax` error message.  So with my limited knowledge, I can't figure out what my options are now.  Googled around a bit and saw references to using UrlLib or UrlLib2 - but I'm struggling with figuring out how to use either to make my API Call using Digest Authentication.

I would very much like to stick to the Requests module, as it appears to be the simplest and cleanest approach.  Below is a snippet of my code, any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

**PS.**  *My script is not yet finished, as I'm still learning how to parse the response data received.*

**HERE'S MY SCRIPT**

```
#PYTHON MODULE IMPORTS
import sys #Import the Python Sys module - used later to detect the Python version
PythonVersion = sys.version_info.major #Needed to put this global variable up here, so I can use it early
import json #Import the JSON module - used to print the API Call response content in JSON format
if PythonVersion == 3: #Import the REQUESTS and HTTPDigestAuth modules - used to make API Calls if we detect Python version 3
    import requests
    from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
if PythonVersion == 2: #Import the UrlLib module - used to make API Calls if we detect Python version 2
    import urllib

#GLOBAL VARIABLES
NodeSerial = '1234'
NodeIP = '192.168.1.100'
BasePath = 'api/v0.1'
apiURL = f"http://{NodeIP}/{BasePath}/MagiNodes"

#Define the credentials to use
Username='admin'
Passwd='mypassword'

#MAIN ROUTINE
print("This is a test script")
if PythonVersion == 2:
    print("Python Version 2 detected")

elif PythonVersion == 3:
    print("Python Version 3 detected")
    print(f"Now querying MagiLink-{NodeSerial}...")
    Query1 = requests.get(f"{apiURL}/{NodeSerial}", auth=HTTPDigestAuth(Username, Passwd)) #Using an F string
    pretty_Query1 = json.dumps(Query1.json(), indent=3)  #Pretty printing the response content
    print(pretty_Query1)
```

Comment: Please share the error you get while attempting to install requests via pip

Comment: Did you perhaps try to install from within a Python shell, i.e. `>>> pip install requests`? That won't work, you need to do it from a terminal.

Comment: @MichaelRuth - from the terminal, I get "E: Unable to locate package pip".  From within the Python shell, I get "File "<stdin>", line 1 pip install requests SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: @AlexHall - yes, one attempt was from within the Python shell.  I've even tried  python -m pip install requests but I get "/usr/bin/python: No module named pip"

Comment: You need to install pip, "/usr/bin/python: No module named pip" means that it's not installed. Find the correct package in your package manager and install it. If you're on a linux system, the package name is likely something similar to python27-pip.

Comment: @MichaelRuth - yeah I suspect that much and I've tried all the ways I know how to search for an install pip, but keep getting the same unable to locate package.  I know the router is running a version of Debian, but I've reached out to Ubiquiti support as well to help figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: @MichaelRuth - I just came across this article with information on adding Debian packages to the router (https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/205202560-EdgeRouter-Add-Debian-Packages-to-EdgeOS).  Reading through it now.

Comment: @KismetAgbasi, since it's Debian, it should be as simple as an apt search followed by an apt-get install <package name>